# Uncaught referenceerror e is not defined ERROR in my script Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have a site building with Wordpress

http://eventos.dac-proiect.ro/

On the first page is a slider, jquery script that has built me this error.

```
Uncaught referenceerror e is not defined
```

This is my script:

```
  (function($) {

   var firstImage = $('#slider-content .slider-img:first').index();
   var lastImage = $('#slider-content .slider-img:last').index();

   var currentImage = firstImage
   var nextImage = firstImage + 1
   var prevImage = lastImage

   var sliderImages = $('#slider-content .slider-img');
   var sliderContent = $('#slider-content');

   var sliderImageWidth = parseFloat(sliderImages.eq(0).css('width'));

   $('#button-next').click(function() {
       nextImage = currentImage == lastImage ? firstImage : currentImage + 1;
       sliderContent.animate({ "left": -nextImage * sliderImageWidth });
       currentImage = nextImage;
       e.preventDefault();   //ERROR
   });
   $('#button-prev').click(function() {
       prevImage = currentImage == firstImage ? lastImage : currentImage - 1;
       sliderContent.animate({ "left": -prevImage * sliderImageWidth });
       currentImage = prevImage;
       e.preventDefault();  //ERROR
   });
})(jQuery);
```

This is the code where I integrated script Functions.PHP

```
  add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','my_script_method');

function my_script_method()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('script', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/slider/js/jquery-slider.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
    wp_enqueue_style('script-style',  get_template_directory_uri().'/js/slider/css/style.css');

}
```

I searched information about this error and found that a library should be added udev ... but do not know where

Can you help me to solve this problem please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try passing e as a parameter in your function like so: function(`e`) for both the previous button and next button

Comment: unfortunately still does not work

Comment: at you slider works if you put that parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your click handlers. The last line of each is `e.preventDefault();` but `e` is never defined. Pass it into your anonymous functions.

Example:

```
$('#button-next').click(function(e) {
```

Comment: error disappeared ... can you tell me please if you are functioning slider?

Comment: I've had a look at your site and the slider isn't doing anything for me.